# Looking for freeware SQL Server query tool that requires no install

Tags: sql-server-2008

Looking for freeware SQL Server query tool that requires no install.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a couple to look at that are just exe's:

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - New and up to date.  Can do straight sql querying....

[Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) * looks pretty old so not sure if it'll work on newer dbs....

Comment: Excellent. Q Express is what I was looking for. I couldn't remember the name. Good to know that LINQPad isn't just for LINQ, too. By the way, it worked too on SQL 2008 r2. ty!

Comment: Here's another open-source lightweight standalone tool that I built, pretty simple and straight to the point, just type the query and hit execute : https://github.com/mmghv/QuickQuery